# PrimeNG - Unable to import GrowlModule

Tags: angular, typescript, angular5, primeng

PrimeNg version : "^6.0.0"

Library at [enter link description here](https://primefaces.org/primeng/#/growl)

Getting following error while importing GrowlModule from PrimeNg Library.

> ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): Error: Fetch error: 403 Forbidden
>     Instantiating http://localhost:30006/node_modules/rxjs
>     Loading http://localhost:30006/node_modules/primeng/components/common/messageservice.js
>     Loading ../../../xeeva-p2p-home/app/requisitioning/requisitioning.module
>   Error: Fetch error: 403 Forbidden

using following code to import component in **@NgModule**

```
import { GrowlModule } from 'primeng/growl';

imports: [GrowlModule]
```

While other modules like SliderModule, DataScrollerModule are loading properly.

Can anyone help what I am doing wrong here.

Comment: Which version of PrimeNG do you use ?

Comment: @Antikhippe It is 6.0.0

Comment: @Mayank your project is generated with angular cli? what version of angular cli? are you using angular 5 or 6?

Comment: Can you compare with my working [StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-vhs6d1) ?

Answer (score 0):

according to PrimeNG 6.0.2 Released Growl has deprecated "Toast is the new addition to the suite to replace the deprecated Growl in the long run"

https://www.primefaces.org/primeng-6-0-2-released/